# Taylor expansion for $W^{2,2}$-function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and assume that $u\in W^{2,2}_{loc}(\Omega)$. Let $B_\varepsilon(y)\subset\subset \Omega$ be a ball of radius $\varepsilon$ centered at $y\in\Omega$. I want to estimate $\int_{B_\varepsilon(y)}|\nabla u(x) - \nabla u(y)|^2 \,dx$.

Can I use something like
$|\nabla u(x) - \nabla u(y)| \leq |\nabla^2 u(\xi)| |x-y|$
where $\xi$ is some point in $B_\varepsilon (y)$?

I need to show that $\|\nabla u - \nabla u(y)\|_{L^2(B_\varepsilon)} = O(\varepsilon^{1+\gamma})$ with $\gamma\in(0,1)$ but, I think, I am not be able to get that $\nabla u\in C_{loc}^{0,\gamma}(\Omega)$.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. You can't embed $W^{2,2}_{loc}$ in $C^{1,\gamma}$ in two dimensions. In fact, you can't even embed this space in $L^\infty$. So $\nabla u(y)$ is not well defined. But there are BMO estimates available in that case which replace $\nabla u(y)$ with the average of $\nabla u$ over the ball. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_mean_oscillation .

Comment: Then I would get  $\|\nabla u\|_{BMO}\leq C \|\nabla^2 u\|_{L^2(B_\varepsilon)}$, which implies $\|\nabla u - \nabla u |_{B_\varepsilon}\|_{L^2(B_\varepsilon)} \leq |B_\varepsilon|^{1/2}  C \|\nabla^2 u\|_{L^2(B_\varepsilon)}$ but it still does not provide the estimate of the order $O(\varepsilon^{1+\gamma})$...

Comment: Maybe the estimate does not hold.

Comment: Yes, maybe it is true.Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: If **additionally** $u$ satisfies a differential equation, then you may be able to appeal to Cacciopoli estimates.